# Problem to rotate picture in counterclockwise direction in Action Script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image-rotation

in a .swf object, i rotate pictures in one direction : clockwise (+90°), with the eventRotateHit function. It works!

I need to create a counterclockwise (-90°) function : eventRotateHit2.
This function doesn't work : the picture disappear.
I think it's because the rotation center is false, but i'm not sure. And i don't know how to change it.

Can you help me please?

Frederic

My code :

```
package Classes.image

{
        import fl.controls.Button;
        import flash.display.Bitmap;
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import Classes.utils.*;
        import Classes.*;
        import flash.events.*;
        import flash.text.TextField;
        import flash.text.StyleSheet;
        import flash.utils.ByteArray;
        import flash.display.BitmapData;
        import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

        public class imgBox extends MovieClip
        {
                public var _img                                 : imgHelper;
                private var _MAX_WIDTH                          : Number;
                private var _MAX_HEIGHT                         : Number;
                private var boxFrame:MovieClip;
                private var statusMsg:TextField;

                public var byteData:ByteArray;

                public function imgBox(w:Number,h:Number,_bitmap:Bitmap) 
                {
                        _MAX_WIDTH = w;
                        _MAX_HEIGHT = h;

                        var borderColor:uint  = 0x666666;
                        var borderSize:uint   = 1;
                        var vMenu:verticalMenu;

                        _img = new imgHelper(_bitmap);
                        _img.addEventListener("invalidate", eventImageInvalidated);
                        if ( _bitmap.width > _MAX_WIDTH || _bitmap.height > _MAX_HEIGHT ) 
                                 _img.resizePic(_MAX_WIDTH, _MAX_HEIGHT, false);

                        boxFrame = new MovieClip;
                        boxFrame.graphics.lineStyle(borderSize, borderColor);
                        boxFrame.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _img.width+4,_img.height+4);
                        addChild(boxFrame);

                        addChild(_img);
                        boxFrame.x = 60 + _img.theImage.x;
                        boxFrame.y = _img.theImage.y;
                        _img.x = 62;
                        _img.y = 2;

                        //vMenu = new verticalMenu();
                        //var myMenu:Array = new Array( { label:'Rotate', _function:eventRotateHit } );// ,
                                                                        //      { label:'Upload', _function:eventUploadHit } );
                        //vMenu.buildMenu(myMenu);

                        var  button:Button = new Button();
                        button.label = Local.getInstance().getString("rotate");
                        button.width = 50;
                        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventRotateHit);
                        addChild(button);

                        var  buttonbis:Button = new Button();
                        buttonbis.label = Local.getInstance().getString("rotate");
                        buttonbis.width = 50;
                        buttonbis.y = 50;
                        buttonbis.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventRotateHit2);
                        addChild(buttonbis);

                }


                private function eventImageInvalidated(e:Event) {
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                        dispatchEvent(new Event("invalidate", true, true));// invalidate for re-encoding the image.

                }

                private function eventUploadHit(e:*) {
                        trace('Upload Hit');
                        this.dispatchEvent(new Event("uploadImage"));
                }

                public function showStatus(msg:String) {
                                TweenLite.to(boxFrame, 0.5, { height: _img.height + 24 } );
                                var vMenu:verticalMenu = new verticalMenu();;
                                if (statusMsg){
                                        removeChild(statusMsg);
                                        statusMsg = null;
                                }
                                statusMsg = new TextField();
                                statusMsg.htmlText = msg;
                                statusMsg.styleSheet = vMenu._textStyleSheet;
                                statusMsg.width = _img.width;
                                addChild(statusMsg);
                                statusMsg.y = _img.height + 2;
                                statusMsg.x = boxFrame.x + 10;

                }

                public function hideStatus(msg:String = "") {
                                if (statusMsg){
                                        removeChild(statusMsg);
                                        statusMsg = null;
                                }
                                TweenLite.to(boxFrame, 0.5, { height: _img.height + 4 } );
                }

                private function eventRotateHit(e:*) {
                        trace('rotate Image');
                        if (statusMsg){
                                        removeChild(statusMsg);
                                        statusMsg = null;
                                }

                        _img.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
                        _img.resizePic(_MAX_WIDTH, _MAX_HEIGHT, false);
                        boxFrame.width = _img.width + 4;
                        boxFrame.height = _img.height + 4;

                        boxFrame.x = 60 + _img.theImage.x;
                        boxFrame.y = _img.theImage.y;

                }

                private function eventRotateHit2(e:*) {
                        trace('rotate Image');
                        if (statusMsg){
                                        removeChild(statusMsg);
                                        statusMsg = null;
                                }

                        _img.rotate((-1)*Math.PI/2);
                        _img.resizePic(_MAX_WIDTH, _MAX_HEIGHT, false);
                        boxFrame.width = _img.width + 4;
                        boxFrame.height = _img.height + 4;

                        boxFrame.x = 60 + _img.theImage.x;
                        boxFrame.y = _img.theImage.y;           

                }

                public function dispose() {

                }

                public function prepare(w:Number, h:Number, q:Number) {
                        var btData:BitmapData = _img.resizeBitmapData(w, h);
                        byteData = new JPGEncoder(q).encode(btData);

                }

        }

}
```

here the rotate function:

```
package Classes.utils
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import Classes.*;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class imgHelper extends MovieClip
    {
        public var tt:TextField;
        public var theImage:Bitmap;
        private var myMask:MovieClip;


        private var _boxDimW:Number;
        private var _boxDimH:Number;




        public function imgHelper(img:Bitmap=null) 
        {
            theImage = img;
            if (theImage)
                addChild(theImage);
             tt = new TextField;
            tt.text = '0%';
        /*  addChild(tt);*/

        }

        public override function get width():Number {
            return theImage.width;
        }

        public override function get height():Number {
            return theImage.height;
        }
        public  function get _scaleX():Number {
            return theImage.scaleX;
        }
        public  function set _scaleX(sx) {
             theImage.scaleX = sx;
        }

        public  function get _scaleY():Number {
            return theImage.scaleY;
        }
        public  function set _scaleY(sy:Number) {
             theImage.scaleY = sy;
        }

        public function load(url:String)
        {
            //trace('loading : ' + url);
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, picLoaded);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errLoading);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
            var lContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true);



            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            try {
                loader.load(request,lContext);


            } catch (error:Error) {
                trace("Unable to load requested document.");
            }

        }
        private function progress(e:ProgressEvent)
        {
            tt.text = Math.round(e.bytesLoaded /e.bytesTotal *100) + '%';
        }

        private function errLoading(e:*)
        {
            tt.visible = false;
            dispatchEvent(new Event("imgLoaded",true,true));
        }

        private function picLoaded(e:*)
        {
            var picLoader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
            theImage = Bitmap(picLoader.content);
            addChild(theImage);

            tt.visible = false;
            dispatchEvent(new Event("imgLoaded",true,true));
        }

        public function resizePic(rW:Number,rH:Number,crop:Boolean=false)
        {
            var img = theImage;
            _boxDimW = rW;
            _boxDimH = rH;

            if (img.width > img.height)
            {
                img.width = rW;
                img.height = img.height * img.scaleX;
            }
            else
            {
                img.height = rH;
                img.width = img.width * img.scaleY;
            }


            if (crop)
            {
                if (img.width < img.height)
                {
                    var oldScaleX = img.scaleX;
                    img.width = rW;
                    img.scaleY += img.scaleX-oldScaleX;

                }
                else
                {
                    var oldScaleY = img.scaleY;
                    img.height = rH;
                    img.scaleX += img.scaleY-oldScaleY;

                }

                maskIt(rW, rH);

            }
            else {
                if (img.height < img.width) {
                    img.y=(rH-img.height)/2
                }
                else {
                    img.x=(rW-img.width)/2

                }
            }



        }



        public function resizeBitmapData (rW:Number, rH:Number):BitmapData {
            var img:Bitmap = new Bitmap(theImage.bitmapData);
            trace('resize bitmap : ' + img.height + '-' + img.width);
            trace('resize bitmap : ' + rH + '-' + rW);
            if (img.width > img.height) {
                    if (img.height>rH)
                        rH = img.height * (rW / img.width);
                    else{ // do not resize
                        rH = img.height;
                        rW = img.width;
                    }
            }
            else {
                if (img.width>rW)
                    rW = img.width * (rH / img.height);
                else{ // do not resize
                        rH = img.height;
                        rW = img.width;
                    }

            }

            var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rW, rH);
            var scaleMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix( rW / img.width , 0, 0, rH / img.height   , 0,0);
            var colorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
            bmpData.draw(theImage, scaleMatrix , colorTransform, null, null, true);
            return (bmpData);
        }

        public function rotate(dir:Number) {


            var workingImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(theImage.bitmapData.clone());
            var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(workingImage.height, workingImage.width);
            var transMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix(Math.cos(dir),Math.sin(dir),-Math.sin(dir),Math.cos(dir), workingImage.height,0);
            var colorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
            bmpData.draw(workingImage, transMatrix, colorTransform, null, null, true);
            TweenLite.to(theImage, 0.5, { autoAlpha:0 } );
            //removeChild(theImage);
            theImage = new Bitmap(bmpData);
            addChild(theImage);
            //trace(theImage.y + '--' + theImage.x+'--'+theImage.height+'--'+theImage.width);
            if (theImage.height < theImage.width) {
                    theImage.y += (_boxDimH - theImage.height) / 2
                }
                else {
                    theImage.x +=(_boxDimW-theImage.width)/2

                }


            theImage.alpha = 0;
            TweenLite.to(theImage, 1, { autoAlpha:1 } );
            trace('sending event !');
            dispatchEvent(new Event("invalidate", true, true));// invalidate for re-encoding the image.
        }


        public function maskIt(w:Number, h:Number)
        {
            if (myMask) {
                removeChild(myMask);
                myMask = null;
            }
            myMask = new MovieClip();
            myMask.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
            myMask.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, w,h);
            addChild(myMask);
            this.mask = myMask;
        }

        public function dispose() {

        }

    }

}
```

thanks for all!!!

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your function, aside from the code snippet being too long and not correctly formatted (you might want to use the {} button).  I'm afraid we cannot help you, unless you clarify what "doesn't work" means, and post the code to the "rotate" function from your imgHelper class.

Comment: @user563685: Just an unrelated tip: instead of `_img.rotate((-1)*Math.PI/2);` you can do `_img.rotate(Math.PI/-2);`

Comment: @weltraumpirat thank you for the comment : i add the rotate function and the clarification

Comment: @nikc thx! it's better, it's true! But the problem still remains :(

Comment: please, take atleast a second to look over your post and it's formatting. i've fixed it once for you already.

Comment: @grapefrukt It's true! Mea Culpa! It's ok now! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the rotation matrix:

Your Bitmap rotates around its origin (0,0), so at 90 degrees, it is located outside of the viewable area to the left.  For this reason, you have translated it along the x axis by the original image's height - and it works.

Now when you rotate the image to 270 degrees (or -90 degrees, just the same), it is located ABOVE the viewable area .  So you will now have to translate it along the y axis by the original image's width:

```
var dir:Number = Math.PI*1.5; // the same as 3*Math.PI/2
var a:Number = Math.cos(dir);
var b:Number = Math.sin(dir);
var c:Number = -b;
var d:Number = a;
var transMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix(a,b,c,d,0,workingImage.width);
```

Comment: Yes!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!! I understand my mistake and now, it works very well!!! Sorry, i can't vote because i don't have any reputation point. But thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are in need of short rotation, this is a formula to find the shortest way to the new direction. Problem with rotation is if you rotate (using normal rotation property) from 0 to -90 with a speed of 1, it will need (360-90=) 270 steps. With short rotation you will only need 90 steps (since most circles are 360 degrees).

I hope you this piece of code will help exploring short rotation:

```
    var startValue:int = targetMC.rotation = 0;
    var endValue:int = -90;
    var position:Number = 0; // should always be ratio betweeen 0-1

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

    function update(e:Event=null):void
    {
        if (position < 1)
        {
         position += 0.05;
         targetMC.rotation = startValue + (((endValue - startValue + 540) % 360) - 180) * position;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ... But, i do a short rotation : Math.pi/-2 is the same that -90, no? I think my problem is in the rotate function, now. I can't totally redo :(

Comment: -90 is the end value. It could be any number where you want to rotate to. I think it is in the rotate function, so you need to implement that rotation formula like I am using in the example. Hope that helps.

Comment: He is rotating Bitmap pixels, not rotating a DisplayObject.

Comment: He is already going the shortest way, and also, the % operator never completely solves this problem, your version fails on startValue=0 endValue=-710